# Changing internal table without header using index

Tags: abap, internal-tables

How to change the old BW3.x code (tables with header) to BW7.x (tables without header)

OLD code:

```
LOOP AT p_package.
  gv_tabix = sy-tabix.
  " changing header ... and more
  MODIFY p_package INDEX gv_tabix.
```

Here the header line gets changed and the table is updated using `modify` and `index`

Unfortunately I do not see how to use the `index` keyword on tables without a header.

So far I coded:

```
LOOP AT p_package into p_package_line.
  gv_tabix = sy-tabix.
  " changing p_package_line ...
  MODIFY table p_package from p_package_line
```

But I'm not sure if it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a field symbol. This eliminates the need to explicitly `MODIFY` the table completely:

```
LOOP AT p_package ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<package_line>).
  <package_line>-foo = 'bar'.
ENDLOOP.
```

(or for older versions)

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS <package_line> TYPE LINE OF p_package.
LOOP AT p_package ASSIGNING <package_line>.
  <package_line>-foo = 'bar'.
ENDLOOP.
```

If you want to stick to the use of `MODIFY`:

```
MODIFY p_package FROM p_package_line INDEX foobarhyperprefixstuffthingy_tabix.
```

(And yes, [it's in the documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/de/abapmodify_itab_index.htm) :-)).